# how to get a field name knowing id number in django

Tags: django

I have the following query set to get the subcategory name  knowing the id number:

```
query_sc = Post_Sub_Category.objects.filter(id='1').values('sub_category_name')
```

it gave me the following output:

```
{'sub_category_name': 'car'}
```

how can I get only the car? I mean I need the output to be a car only 'the value not the dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `values_list` instead of `values`, here's a quote straight from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list):

> A common need is to get a specific field value of a certain model instance. To achieve that, use values_list() followed by a get() call:

```
>>> Entry.objects.values_list('headline', flat=True).get(pk=1)
'First entry'
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're looking for [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list). With values_list you can get only the values, and if you want a flat list you can do the following.

```
Post_Sub_Category.objects.filter(id='1').values_list('sub_category_name', flat=True)
```

And the result will be `["car"]`